# Font choice in moderncv banking style inconsistent with other styles

Tags: fonts, luatex, moderncv

I'm making experiments with moderncv for didactic purposes, with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

It seems that when I use the `\moderncvstyle{classic}` style (or the majority of others) I can easily specify the fonts to use in the document with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`.
Anyway, if I switch to the `\moderncvstyle{banking}` style, it doesn't work anymore.
I can in this case opt for a `\usepackage{fouriernc}` which seems to work, but I don't understand which other fonts I might find available, since for example the `\usepackage{crimson}` which I often use doesn't work.

What causes this inconsistency between styles? What other fonts are available for the `banking` style and how should I discover them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the font after the theme:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\setmainfont{Lobster Two}

% personal data
\name{Jane}{Doe}
\title{My CV}                               
\address{address, city, postal}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{(+30) 325245345}    

\email{test@gmail.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{en.linkedin.com/in/test}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well... somehow magically, it works.

Comment: @user9137 it's not really magical :) the `banking` theme loads the TeX Gyre Pagella font (a Palatino variant), which overrides fontspec settings that have been made before. You can do the same: provide the font setting afterwards, then it will override the setting made by the theme.

Comment: Was suspecting something of this kind after your answer, but I was really not noticing that `banking` was indeed changing the font. Thanks! (But why `\usepackage` was anyway changing it even if invoked before the style, and why `fouriernc` yes but others not?)

Comment: @user9137 the `fourier` packages perform a quite involved font setup, I guess `tgpagella` (as loaded by `moderncv`) isn't really expecting that and does not properly overwrite the settings. In any case you are not supposed to mix different font loading packages and/or methods in one document, so font packages are only guaranteed to work if there are no interfering other packages. In this case you are forced to do that because of what `moderncv` does, and it seems to work, but it would be better if `moderncv` would make the font loading optional.